# How to use PHP to send javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I posted a more specific question on this yesterday, but I think my problem is more basic than what I initially asked.

I am trying to use PHP to set a setTimeout() with a wait variable from a database, but any script I echo doesn't work, even if it involves no PHP manipulation. Take a look below.

Here is the ajax call

```
function loadContent()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "controller/loadContent.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
            $("#contentWindow").html(html);
        }
    });
}
// Initial Load
loadContent();
```

And here is the PHP it receives.

```
        echo '<h1>Upload content to start the show</h1>';

        echo '<script>
        setTimeout(loadContent, 4000);
        </script>';
```

The  is showing, so I believe the ajax and the PHP is working properly. The script works properly when I place it inside the javascript file, but the script won't run when it's echoed to the page.

My problem is the javascript I echo doesn't run. How can I use PHP to send javascript to the user? Why is what I wrote not functioning?

UPDATE: I realized that when I echo script, it echoed to the middle of the body and technically is above where the script file is loaded on the bottom of the body. Can I echo to the bottom of the body?

Comment: Not very clear what is your problem, but there is difference between `.text(someCode)` and `.html(someCode)`. You must evaluate code to run it (first one will not evaluate, while second one do evaluate)

Comment: My problem is the javascript I echo in the PHP isn't running. I'm guessing you're referring to the success. The .html(html). Should I see if using .text(html) works?

Comment: Why do not use the setTimeout in your javascript?

Comment: Because after I get it working, I'll be using PHP to manipulate the setTimeout duration. Also, I want to understand the problem.

Comment: I had this very same problem a while ago and I solved it by performing a check over the echo, but sadly this project is saved on my homePC so I cant see how I solved it back then again. So I'll try to post my solution as soon as I get home, which is in little over 2 hours, but I can tell you it was pretty efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a workaround:*

```
function loadContent()
{
$.ajax(
{
    url: "controller/loadContent.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        var myArray = html.split("|");
        var message = myArray[0];
        var counter = parseInt(myArray[1]); //Minor fix
        $("#contentWindow").html(message);
        startCounter(counter);
    }
});
}

function startCounter(counter){
    //counter as the value of 1000 milliseconds are equal to 1 second
    setTimeout(loadContent, counter);
}
```

*PHP File*

```
$refreshTimer = 1000; //This is a test
echo "Upload content to start the show|".$refreshTimer; //The message and the counter
```

Comment: It seems to be working. I'll keep implementing and testing it and will let you know. Can you explain what I was doing wrong, and why this works?

Comment: I'm using | instead of / to split so I can keep using tags in my HTML. I recommend changing this in your HTML.

Comment: When you are returning a string with javascript code from php via ajax, you need to evaluate this code on the client in order to make it work, but, the use of `eval` is considered a bad practice,so this is a better workaround than using `eval`

Comment: I'm trying to replace the number with a php variable like so.     echo '|'.$refreshTimer.''; Instead, it's setting the counter to one second. Do I need to parse the variable in some way?

Comment: Nope, counter is still set to 1 second. The $refreshTimer variable is still echoing the correct amount of time (60000). Do I need to parse it to a Int, and if so, do I do so in PHP or javascript?

Comment: Is still setting to one second in the client, right, remember that the delay part of `setTimeOut(function,delay)` is represented in  milliseconds, ergo, 1000 milliseconds are equal to 1 second ;)

Comment: No, 60000 milliseconds are equal to 60 seconds. I echo the variable and it shows 60000, then a second later, 59000, then 58000, and it countinues reloading every second until 60000 has passed. I don't understand why.

Comment: Yes you are right, i corrected the code in order to show the equivalence point....so bassically what you need is to execute loadContent every 6 seconds, right??

Comment: When I put nothing after |, it gives me the same result, so it's probably not receiving a number at all.

Comment: No luck. Even tried turning refreshTimer into Int with intval(), and counter into Int with parseInt(). I'm stuck again, but thank you for your help. It's been a huge step forward.

Comment: Could you please post the result of `console.log(counter)` in the success part of your ajax call??

Comment: Inserting counter = parseInt(counter); fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you return just the script portion in your php file you can set the dataType in the .ajax call to 'script' and it will execute the returned javascript (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

So:

```
function loadContent()
{
   $.ajax(
   {
       url: "controller/loadContent.php",
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'script',
       success: function(html)
       {
           $("#contentWindow").html(html);
       }
  });
}
```

// Initial Load
loadContent();

Then in your PHP:

```
echo 'setTimeout(loadContent, 4000);';
```

Comment: I tried this code, and it never loaded the content. The rest of the javascript on the page worked, so it's valid javascript. Not sure why it didn't load $contentWindow. Let me know if you can correct it, because your solution seems much more straight forward and drier.

Comment: After playing with it, it seems dataType: 'script', is causing the trouble.

Comment: Try removing the <script> tag in your PHP file.